# how to eliminate datatable warning unknown parameter '0' for row 0

Tags: datatables

[error image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTbDi.png)Hi i am using datatable for a project. The retreived records are shown correctly. But everytime the page loads the following warning pop up box is shown "DataTables warning: table id=new_referral_table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4" and the record count at the bottom shows more than shown entries i.e if 3 records are shown it shows 1 to 4 of 4 entries. Can anyone please help?

```
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
<table id="new_table" class="table  table-striped">                     <!-- bootstrap table class and striped table class-->
    <thead>
        <tr>                                            <!-- bootstrap table header class-->
            <th> Request ID</th>
            <th>Request Date</th>                   <!--  table headers or column names under which the record values will be displayed-->
            <th>C_ID</th>

            <th>W_ID</th>

            <th>Status</th>


    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php                                                                                                           /* Php While statement  which loops and gets the values of all the records*/
            while( $row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row1['Req_ID']."</td>";
                    $string1=$row1["Req_Date"]->format('Y-m-d');
                    echo "<td>".$string1."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row1['C_ID']."</td>";

                    echo "<td>".$row1['WID']."</td>";

                    echo "<td>".$row1['Status']."</td>";

                    echo "</tr>";

                }
        ?>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#new_table').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: You have `<tr><tr>..</tr>` ....Eliminate the first `<tr>` ...This is why you get the error.

Comment: @davidkonrad Hi David Thank you for replying. I removed the first <tr> but still nothing changed

Comment: You should also remove the last `</tr>` ...

Comment: @davidkonrad Thank you so much David! Now the warning is gone and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Vik - please mark the answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: @markpsmith Hi Mark i am new to stackoverflow. Can you please tell me how to mark a comment as an answer.

Comment: @Vik - my apologies - I forgot it was a comment and not an answer! you're right, you can't mark a comment as an answer. Silly me.